# Get client local timezone in js

Tags: javascript, timezone, moment-timezone

I want to get the client machine local timezone.

I tried moment-timezone npm package, with the following command

```
moment.tz().zoneAbbr()
```

But it is giving me Universal timezone ie UTC, but I want IST

Can anybody please guide me how to get client machine local time zone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the client's timezone offset in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-offset-in-javascript)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determine-a-users-timezone/22625076#22625076

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want the timezone offset, it is pretty straight forward:

```js
const timezoneOffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();

console.log(timezoneOffset);
```

That will give you whatever the computer is set to.

However, if you want to know the actual timezone, that isn't enough, as there are many time zones for every offset.

There isn't a super direct way to get that curiously. However, you can get it by converting `Date` to a string and using a little regex to grab it:

```js
const date = new Date();
const dateAsString = date.toString();
const timezone = dateAsString.match(/\(([^\)]+)\)$/)[1];

console.log(timezone);
```

That'll give you something like "Eastern Daylight Time" (for me).

If you want to convert that to an abbreviation, you'll have to find a list of possible values and create a mapping function:

```js
const input = 'Eastern Daylight Time';
const tz = {
 'Eastern Daylight Time': 'EDT',
 // add more here
};

const toTZAbbreviation = input => tz[input];

console.log(toTZAbbreviation(input));
```

Answer (score 18):

`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` will return the client's timezone.

```js
const { timeZone } = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions();

console.log(timeZone);
```

Answer (score 1):

The native JS `new Date()` give you the machine timezone. No need for npm packages to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some additional info to @samanime answer.

you will get the time zone from this

```
const dateAsString = date.toString();
const timezone = dateAsString.match(/\(([^\)]+)\)$/)[1];
console.log("timezone", timezone);
```

Now if you want to get the abbreviations or short forms of the timezone like IST, GMT, etc. then just pick the first letter of a string in the timezone.

```
var matches = timezone.match(/\b(\w)/g);
var abbreviations = matches.join('');
console.log("abbreviations", abbreviations);
```

for example: -

timezone: Indian Standard Time

abbreviations: IST